# Query / CSS : no success in to reveal a footer hidden behind a front-page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to reveal a bottom fixed footer (z-index: 1) hidden behind a front page ( z-index: 999,  which should contain a picture) running a script upon click on link...

In real life, this runs well using a trackpad and shipping w 2 fingers the picture to the top...
For user wo a trackpad, I need to insert a linked button to help revealing the footer..

Here is the the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erwin16/tmzbsd0g/)

```
    HTML -------
    <div class="container">
        <div class="front_page">
            <div class="text1">
                <p>Front-page .........</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text2">
               <a id="reveal" href="#">REVEAL FOOTER</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer" data-pages="reveal-footer">
           footer .........
         </div>
    </div>

    CSS --------
    .container { 
        width:100%; 
        position:relative; 
    }
    .front_page { 
        width:100%; 
        background: yellow; 
        position:absolute; 
        z-index:1000; 
    }
    .text1 {
        height: 200px;
    }
    .text2 {
        height: 400px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 32px;
    }

    .footer { 
        width:100%; 
        height:100px; 
        background: blue;
        color: white;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

   --SCRIPT 
    var myEl = document.getElementById('reveal');

    myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var _elem = $('[data-pages="reveal-footer"]');
        setHeight();
            function setHeight(){
                var h = _elem.outerHeight();
                alert('_elem.outerHeight: ' + h);
                alert(JSON.stringify( _elem.prev()));
                _elem.prev().css({ 'margin-bottom':h })
            }
        $(window).resize(function(){
          setHeight();
        })  
        //alert('reveal the footer elemen _elem !' + _elem);
    }, false);
```

Comment: Update `z-index` of footer. Check updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tmzbsd0g/12/

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add this line:

```
$('.footer').css('z-index', 1001);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tmzbsd0g/11

Comment: Although, this will 'cover' part of the picture ('front page'). Looking at erwin's code, I _think_ he wants to append the footer to the page so it doesn't actually cover the image. I _think_....

Comment: the footer don't hides "front page" text. I don't know where is the problem

Comment: Really? e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/tmzbsd0g/13/.  erwin says that the yellow box is actually a picture, so I can imagine he wont want to lose that picture. _It's not really clear what's being asked for though._

Comment: So all yellow box is a picture, the footer gaps inside there and he doesn't wants it. Why footer don't position just after the yellow box? Why is in this position? What OP are asking? Maybe this should be closed

Comment: Thanks guys, for taking time to think about this issue,Dave is right, on my test site I have a big picture on the front page, and the footer is hidden behind...  using the tracpad it's very easy to 'raise' the picture ( so the top of it is out of view by the same height as the footer and the footer is visible....  scrolling down with2 fingers, the pictures comes back down and the footer is covered again...

unfortunately this doesn't work with a standard mouse ..... so I am thinking to add a button (up /down)  to make it happen .. you may have a better guess ..